# django doesn't response right packet but it shows 200 in console

Tags: django, sockets, networking

I develop a django(1.5) app, but yesterday I found it could not get a response sometimes and shows a blank page.

The bad-working url is: `http://www.anwcl.com:8000/comment/`

But local url works all right(django serves on my computer): `http://127.0.0.1:8000/comment/`

I add a `print data` in wsgi's `finish_response`, before `self.write(data)`, and the data looks like all right, but it doesn't send right packets out. Wireshark shows it responsed several packets, but they are not completed with a good end, some packets missed.

Here are the image-captures of wireshark(NOTE I serve django on my computer, so I access `http://www.anwcl.com:8000/comment/` means I visit my computer):

- `http://www.anwcl.com/test/error/django_response_truncated_detail.jpg`
  `http://www.anwcl.com/test/error/django_response_good_one.jpg`
  `http://www.anwcl.com/test/error/django_response_bad_one.jpg`
  `http://www.anwcl.com/test/error/django_request_but_no_response.jpg`

As the first 3 images, it could only response 3 packets, and the last 2 miss.

And as the 4th image, sometimes it even doesn't response with any packet, even though the console shows `[15/Dec/2013 12:37:49] "GET /comment/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6095`.

And once I reduce the response size(remove most things in template), then it works all right!

I wonder if there is any existing bug/limitation when I response with a big html.

And here are more details of my configurations, and urls.

server configuration:

```
runserver --noreload 0.0.0.0:8000
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

from d1.views import *
from vine_comment.views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    url(r'^matrix/?$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='matrix/matrix.html'), name='matrix'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='index'),
    url(r'^comment/(?P<url_b64>.*?)/?$', CommentView.as_view(), name='comment'),
)

from functools import wraps
from django.contrib.staticfiles.views import serve as serve_static

if settings.DEBUG:

    def custom_headers(view_func):

        @wraps(view_func)
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
            return response

        return wrapper

    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'iframe/(?P<url_b64>.*?)/?$', custom_headers(CommentIframeView.as_view()), name='comment_iframe'),
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', custom_headers(serve_static)),
    )
```

Comment: First I should say response status 200 just means that server has successfully created a response packet and sent it; it doesn't assure you that it would be your desire response. Second, since you talked about reducing response size, it seems there is a speed or size limitation on server or the line you are using.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi Thanks, I test it via my android phone, and another computer, they can get the right response, only on the server itself the error happens. I think it may be a error of **server access itself**? I don't think it's a speed limitation because the traffic is small(kb), and I think the response texts is good, but they couldn't be sent out correctly.

Comment: I'm happy you solved it. I ran into similar issue yesterday about connecting to a database to perform an insertion.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi Not yet. On server it happens frequently..

Comment: Is it really necessary to send a lot of data? I mean can't you just perform some operations in client-side just to reduce response size?

Comment: No, just a little data, very little. I restart my computer several times, and found that the problem appears randomly, and appears on any site. Strange that I've only used eclipse and chrome.

Comment: Have you checked your DNS and proxy settings; maybe even OS services? You must be sure if all required services are running.

Comment: Yes. I've carefully checked my DNS and proxy. DNS is a public one: 114.114.114.114(like 8.8.8.8), proxy is not used when I'm testing the websites. I've checked my domain-ip list(ipconfig /displaydns) and found them all right. OS services have not been checked because I'm not sure what services are needed.

Comment: Have you tried changing your IDE. You can use PyCharm instead; I've never got a problem with that.

Comment: Please let me know if helps or not; your problem sounds really strange. There is some bug back there, not in your methods.